# How to fix Out of START_ARRAY token Error

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

Can anybody say where I am doing wrong. I have json like that

```
[{"name":"foo","slug":"foo2","locales":["foo3"],"hostname":"foo4","region_tag":"foo5"},{"name":"foo","slug":"foo2","locales":["foo3"],"hostname":"foo4","region_tag":"foo5"},{"name":"foo","slug":"foo2","locales":["foo3"],"hostname":"foo4","region_tag":"foo5"},{"name":"foo","slug":"foo2","locales":["foo3"],"hostname":"foo4","region_tag":"foo5"}]
```

And I parse to this class.

```
@JsonSerialize(include = JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
"shards"
})

public class ShardsResponse extends Response{

@JsonProperty("shards")
private List<Shards> shards = new ArrayList<Shards>();

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The shards
 */
@JsonProperty("shards")
public List<Shards> getShards() {
    return shards;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param shards
 *     The shards
 */
@JsonProperty("shards")
public void setShards(List<Shards> shards) {
    this.shards = shards;
}
}
```

And Shards class is :

```
/**


* 
 * @return
 *     The locales
 */
@JsonProperty("locales")
public List<String> getLocales() {
    return locales;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param locales
 *     The locales
 */
@JsonProperty("locales")
public void setLocales(List<String> locales) {
    this.locales = locales;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The name
 */
@JsonProperty("name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param name
 *     The name
 */
@JsonProperty("name")
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The hostname
 */
@JsonProperty("hostname")
public String getHostname() {
    return hostname;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param hostname
 *     The hostname
 */
@JsonProperty("hostname")
public void setHostname(String hostname) {
    this.hostname = hostname;
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 *     The slug
 */
@JsonProperty("slug")
public String getSlug() {
    return slug;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param slug
 *     The slug
 */
@JsonProperty("slug")
public void setSlug(String slug) {
    this.slug = slug;
}
}
```

So I'm using `ObjectMapper.readValue(jsontext, responseclass)`

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(JsonString);

JsonString = "";
Iterator<String> keys= object.keys();

while (keys.hasNext()){

    String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
    JsonString= JsonString+ object.getString(keyValue);
}

JsonString= JsonString.substring(1, JsonString.length()-1);

Object response = ObjectMapper.readValue(JsonString, ShardsResponse.class);
```

At the last I am getting `out of START_ARRAY token`. Please anybody tell me what's wrong.

Cause I'm trying so much things, but I never find the solution.

How can I fix it.

Comment: your string is not a valid json!

Comment: the server's api just gave me like this. I changed it just dummy datas. So how can I fix the json then @MohammadRahchamani

Comment: see my answer, there's an example for you!

Comment: You must be having problems parsing your data as a JSONObject, because it is a JSONArray (starts with [ and ends with ]).

Answer (score 2):

Your json string is correct, but not for the object you expect, as someone mentioned already, you need to  use a List

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jackson.type.TypeReference;


public class ParseJson {

    private static final String jsonString = "[{\"name\":\"foo\",\"slug\":\"foo2\",\"locales\":[\"foo3\"],\"hostname\":\"foo4\",\"region_tag\":\"foo5\"},{\"name\":\"foo\",\"slug\":\"foo2\",\"locales\":[\"foo3\"],\"hostname\":\"foo4\",\"region_tag\":\"foo5\"},{\"name\":\"foo\",\"slug\":\"foo2\",\"locales\":[\"foo3\"],\"hostname\":\"foo4\",\"region_tag\":\"foo5\"},{\"name\":\"foo\",\"slug\":\"foo2\",\"locales\":[\"foo3\"],\"hostname\":\"foo4\",\"region_tag\":\"foo5\"}]";

    public static void parse()  {

        try {

            TypeReference<List<Shards>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<Shards>>() { };
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            List<Shards> list = mapper.readValue(jsonString, typeRef);

            for ( Shards s : list )
            {
                s.printDebug();
            }

            ShardsResponse sr = new ShardsResponse(list);
            String srString = mapper.writeValueAsString(sr);

            System.out.println("srString: " + srString );

            TypeReference<ShardsResponse> typeRef2 = new TypeReference<ShardsResponse>() { };
            ShardsResponse sr2 = mapper.readValue(srString, typeRef2);

            sr2.printDebug();


        } catch ( IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       ParseJson.parse();
    }

}
```

Edit: 
If you expect a ShardsResponse back, your json string should look like this:

```
{"shards":[{"locales":["foo3"],"name":"foo","hostname":"foo4","slug":"foo2","region_tag":"foo5"},{"locales":["foo3"],"name":"foo","hostname":"foo4","slug":"foo2","region_tag":"foo5"},{"locales":["foo3"],"name":"foo","hostname":"foo4","slug":"foo2","region_tag":"foo5"},{"locales":["foo3"],"name":"foo","hostname":"foo4","slug":"foo2","region_tag":"foo5"}]}
```

Easiest way to figure out what the json will look like is to dump it out:

```
ShardsResponse sr = new ShardsResponse(list);
String srString = mapper.writeValueAsString(sr);
System.out.println("srString: " + srString );
```

Edit:

Adding additional Classes for clarity:

ShardsResponses.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ShardsResponse {

    private List<Shards> shards = new ArrayList<Shards>();

    public ShardsResponse() { }

    public ShardsResponse( List<Shards> shards)
    {
        this.shards = shards;
    }

    public List<Shards> getShards() {
        return shards;
    }

    public void setShards(List<Shards> shards) {
        this.shards = shards;
    }

    public void  printDebug()
    {
        for ( Shards s : shards)
        {
             s.printDebug();
             System.out.println("");
        }
    }


}
```

Shards.java:

```
import java.util.List;


public class Shards {

    private List<String> locales;
    private String name;
    private String hostname;
    private String slug;
    private String region_tag;


    public List<String> getLocales() {
        return locales;
    }
    public void setLocales(List<String> locales) {
        this.locales = locales;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getHostname() {
        return hostname;
    }
    public void setHostname(String hostname) {
        this.hostname = hostname;
    }
    public String getSlug() {
        return slug;
    }
    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }
    public void printDebug()
    {
        System.out.println("name: " + name);
        System.out.println("hostname: " + hostname);
        System.out.println("slug: " + slug);
        System.out.println("region_tag: " + region_tag);
        for ( String s : locales )
        {
            System.out.println("Locals: " + locales);
        }
    }
    public String getRegion_tag() {
        return region_tag;
    }
    public void setRegion_tag(String region_tag) {
        this.region_tag = region_tag;
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed it like this, but same all same all. nothing changed. I get same error.

message = "{\"shards\":" + message + "}";

       TypeReference<List<Shards>> typeRef = new TypeReference<List<Shards>>() { };
       ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       List<Shards> list = mapper.readValue(message, typeRef);

Comment: @dummyDroid I have edited my original response and added the full source for the class.  I am able to parse the original json and then the newer ShardsResponse json string.  I did have to add a no args constructor for ShardsResponse since jackson requires it.

Comment: I am still geting the same error. On this line :

ShardsResponse sr2 = mapper.readValue(srString, typeRef2);

I cant through this line.

Is my ShardsResponse class has wrong?
ShardsResponse  class at the up side + add default constructor for your sample.

Comment: @dummyDroid I've added the other two classes to my response, I created these by hand based on the json data, I did not copy yours.  There may be a subtle difference in them.

Answer (score 0):

you have an `jsonArray` but you are trying to parse a `jsonObject`. change your method to return a list of objects instead of one object.

Comment: I changed my code like this, 

message = "{\"data\" : " + message + "}"; 

But still I get the same error. By the way the other json  - at the first - already valid. I checked two json on http://json.parser.online.fr/, both of them are valid.

Comment: oh! my bad! I'm so sorry for my mistake! see my updated answer! :)