# Getting error while passing RequestBody to my RestAPI

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I am creating a simple Rest API using Spring MVC. One of the endpoint takes a JSON string as request body and I wish to map it to a object. Below is the data model:

```
public class StudentDataImpl  {

       private String studentName;
       private String studentHobby;
       private String studentMobile;
       private Date studentDOB;
```

It is working fine for this, but when I am adding 2 more variables i.e. an array list and another class object, the application is giving an error.

Below are the 2 more  variables:

```
private ArrayList<String> studentSkills;
private StudentAddressImpl address;
```

Below is the method that handles the endpoint request:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/students/{studentName}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE )
public StudentDataImpl UpdateStudent(@PathVariable("studentName")  String name, @RequestBody StudentDataImpl student)  {
    

    System.out.println("Student Details are received as below for the given Student "+student.getStudentName());
    System.out.println(student.toString());
        
                    
    return student;
    
}
```

And this is my JSON string:

```
{
    "StudentName": "Mohit Kumar Tyagi",
    "StudentHobby": "Gaming",
    "StudentMobile": "123456789",
    "StudentDOB": "1999-12-25",
    "StudentSkills" : [ "SPRING"],
    "address": [
    {
    "street" : "Street1",
    "city" : "city1",
    "pincode" : "123456",
    "country" : "Country"
    }
    ]
}
```

If I am using this JSON, it gives me the below error:

INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring-dispatcher': initialization completed in 1776 ms
public String ExceptionJSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.mohit.admission.StudentAddressImpl` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.mohit.admission.StudentAddressImpl` out of START_ARRAY token
at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 7, column: 13] (through reference chain: `com.mohit.admission.StudentDataImpl["address"]`)

Comment: this should be helpful...https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.rainerhahnekamp.com/en/spring-mvc-json-serialization/amp/

Answer (score 1):

In your `StudentDataImpl` class, check that `StudentAddressImpl address` is an object , not an array. So it expects something like this in json

```
"address":  { 
    "street"  : "Street1", 
    "city"    : "city1", 
    "pincode" : "123456", 
    "country" : "Country" 
}
```

Not this,

```
"address":  [{ 
    "street"  : "Street1", 
    "city"    : "city1", 
    "pincode" : "123456", 
    "country" : "Country" 
}]
```

You can fix this in two ways, either change the json, which the api is receiving just like I have shown now.
Or change the code to like this.

```
private ArrayList<StudentAddressImpl> address;
```

Comment: If this solves your problem, whould you mind marking it as the right answer ?

Answer (score 0):

JsonMappingException: out of START_ARRAY token exception is thrown by Jackson object mapper as it's expecting an Object {} whereas it found an Array [{}] in response.

Refer below reference

[How to fix Out of START_ARRAY token Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093638/how-to-fix-out-of-start-array-token-error)